# libfmt 9.1: Format `chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock>` as UTC

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono, fmt

I am using `libfmt` version 9.1. I have a `chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock>` time point, which internally keeps its time in UTC. I want to output that time (and date) *without any conversion into the local time zone*.

This is the default behavior in `libfmt` version 10, but in version 9.1, `libfmt` converts the time point into the local time zone. This code:

```cpp
    char e[] = "TZ=:Pacific/Auckland";
    putenv(e);
    tzset();
    auto tp = std::chrono::sys_seconds::min();
    auto tpStr = fmt::format( "{:%F %T %Z}", tp);
    std::cout << tpStr << "\n";
```

outputs `1970-01-01 12:00:00 NZST` when built with `libfmt` v.9.1, and `1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT` when built with `libfmt` v.10. See also [here at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/49MzKqb1b).

I cannot easily update to `libfmt` v.10, because I fear that this change (and maybe others?) may break my project in other places. I am using C++17 and therefore cannot use `std::format`. Is it possible to instruct `libfmt` v.9.1 to format a `chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock>` in UTC?

The `libfmt` docs do not say anything about time zones, neither [in the 9.1 version](https://fmt.dev/9.1.0/syntax.html#chrono-specs) nor [in the latest version](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#chrono-specs). The [std::format docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter#Format_specification) specify a `L` prefix which switches from the default behavior of outputting in `C` locale (i.e., the same default behavior as `libfmt` v.10) to outputting in the "local" timezone. Does `libfmt` v.9.1 by any chance have a "reverse" modifier?